# Returning Highest earning product by date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to figure out my best option of presenting the data and also the formula if needed. I need to find the highest earning product of every month. I am using a pivot but I do not think that is the right analysis tool to use in google sheets. I can only use excel or google sheets. I have columns for the following:

```
Product Name
Sales
Net Revenue
Month #
Month Name
Year
Calendar Quarter
Country
Vertical
Units Sold
Commission
Sales Rep
```

I've tried filtering using different combinations on the pivot table.

```
Column A           Column B
January            Car
February           Truck
March              Hybrid
April              Van
```

Comment: Could you upload some screenshots with the input and expected value?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. If you can use Excel, you can use Pivot Tables to get what you want.

First, because you did not create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I made up some fake data. Let's say you got a list with earnings of each product kind of like this:

[image]

Second, I got an spanish version of Excel 2007 (yeah, old, but it works!), so if you got Excel higher than 2007, the option I will be naming in my answer my have changed a little bit, but indeed they are still there!!

About a solution, I've selected all the data above, and created a Pivot Table like this:

1. DATE and PRODUCT to section rows (DATE must be the first one)
2. EARNING to values section, summing up
3. **Group the DATE field** by month [Group or ungroup data in a PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725)
4. Last step, but important. **Apply a value filter** in field PRODUCT but selecting option TOP 10, and choose TOP 1 by field of SUM OF EARNINGS.

[image]

You will get this Pivot Table:

[image]

As you can see, the Pivot Table shows the max earnings of each month, with the name of the product.

Hope this can help!